# Scorm "Course import error"

Tags: import, scorm1.2

I am trying to make a course I have scorm compliant and when I go to upload the zip file with all the content to scorm I get this error "Course import failed: zip file contained no courses". I am not doubting that I have something configured incorrectly but I am disappointed scorm does not offer any further debugging errors upon getting this callback. I assume it has something to do with my ismanifest.xml file.

I was hoping someone could shed some light on possible reasons why this is happening?

I am not asking for you to debug my error because I realize I have not given you enough information but if you could just help list some reasons why this might be happening it would help me for future reference.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the zip file contains a folder which contains all the scorm files? If this is the case, try zipping the folder contents instead and upload again

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on periklis' post:

SCORM packages require the imsmanifest.xml file to be at the root of the package (ZIP). Sometimes when zipping the course files, a developer inadvertently ZIPs the *folder* containing the files, which causes the manifest to be one folder level deep, not at the root. It's a pretty common mistake.

Check your ZIP to ensure the manifest and other files are not nested in a subfolder.